# 'But', 'except' and 'except for'

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if a native could say which sentence from among the following sentences does not sound correct:

> 1. That child does nothing *but* watch TV.
> 2. That child does nothing *except* watch TV.
> 3. That child does nothing *except for* watch TV.

For me only #3 does not work. Because after 'for we have to use a noun or a gerund, whereas here according to the sentence we have to use infinitive without to (...does watch)
Am I right?

Comment: Yes. 1 and 2 are OK. As you say, 3 should be "That child does nothing except for *watching* TV." But I think 3 is less common as we tend not to add unnecessary extra words (in speech anyway).

Comment: @user3169 but anyway I guess "That child does nothing except for watching TV" is incorrect. Because whereas we had 'does' before except for, we must use a bare infinitive. This is in the manner that after 'for' we have to use a noun and these two are quite contrary to each other. Am I right? :)

Comment: For instance I think in the following example, all of these three can be used:
"She is not interested in anything (but / except / except for) skiing."
Because according to the sentence we have the verb 'interested in' which should be followed by a gerund.
Or as another example in the sentence: "I like all fruits (but / except / except for) oranges", all of these three can be used interchangeably without even a slight nuance.
Could I make myself understood? If yes do you agree with me? ;)

Comment: All I can say is that "That child does nothing except for watching TV." sounds natural for me. I did not write any answer, because someone else would better describe the grammar involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement #1 is perfect.  #2 and #3 strike me as somewhat awkward, although I've heard them used this way often enough.  So I won't say #2 and #3 are outright ungrammatical, but if #1 is available, use it.

Here's why it sounds awkward to me.

"Except and except for" are synonymous with "with the exception of".

**Everyone had a fun time except for me. I couldn't swim because I had poison ivy.**

"Everyone...except for me" makes sense. The *set*  is {people having a good time} and I am the sole exception. I don't belong in the set.  The set contains everyone but me.

But "Does nothing ... with the exception of" doesn't establish a set-with-exception in the same way. With "does nothing" the set is non-action {does nothing}. The empty set.  I suppose one could say that "doing something" doesn't belong in the set of doing nothing, but that doesn't feel quite right to me.

*Except* and *except for* work better with noun phrases than verb phrases.

Comment: Except for 'but' which can be used either with noun or verb phrases perfectly. Am I right? ;)

Comment: Correct. Everyone but you did nothing but complain.